How to get the image from a canvas using Jest/Node/JSDOM?
I want to unit test some fairly complex code that draws on a canvas. When I've had to do similar things in the past using e.g. WPF, I'd call the code that draws, get the image as a bitmap and then assert things about a selection of pixels. I can't see how to get the image out of a canvas in Jest.
I would think something like this contrived example would work:
import {WaitGroup} from '@jpwilliams/waitgroup';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { setupJestCanvasMock } from 'jest-canvas-mock';

setupJestCanvasMock()

describe('The Problem', () => {
    it('gets the image from a canvas', async () => {
        const c = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = c.getContext('2d')
        c.height = 10
        c.width = 10
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(127,0, 127)'
        ctx.moveTo(0,0)
        ctx.lineTo(10,5)
        ctx.stroke()

        const wg = new WaitGroup()
        wg.add(1)
        c.toBlob(b => {
            fs.writeFileSync('image.png', b.arrayBuffer())
            wg.done()
        })
        await wg.wait()
    });
})

But JSDOM's Blob doesn't implement arrayBuffer (it's been an open feature request for 5 years). The suggestion to use fetch didn't help, that's not implemented  in the environment I'm using, and the node-fetch module gives me a syntax error when I try to import it:

  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
...
    Details:

    /.../node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
    import http from 'node:http';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module


    > 6 | import {fetch} from 'node-fetch'


Installing node_fetch@2.7.0 got round that, but then
   const r = await fetch(c.toDataURL())

gives me
Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported

The url is "data:image/png;base64,00", because it turns out jest-canvas-mock is a red herring, I should use the node canvas library, which does at least have some content. But it still isn't an HTTP(S) URL.
There was a suggestion to use blob._buffer, but that's undefined.
I am trying to save it here as what I thought would be the simplest thing to prove the concept. What I actually want is to get hold of the bitmap, so other ways to do that are welcome.
I'm using Node 20.10.0, Jest 29.7.0.

The issue you linked already contains workarounds for arrayBuffer, did you try them? What did not work? "The suggestion to use fetch didn't help, that's not implemented in the environment I'm using" - what is it, old node version? "node-fetch module gives me a syntax error when I try to import it" - what error? If you use old node version, you can always use older package versions that don't contain incompatible syntax

Consider using a Playwright screenshot test, or if you can't use Playwright as a whole, maybe use a library designed for screenshot tests and image diffs like pixelmatch, or something similar to that that works at a higher level. Otherwise, you'll have a difficult time debugging any failures, and you may get a lot of annoying false positives (a pixel being slightly different probably doesn't matter but will make your test fail for no obvious reason).

I found a solution, it's actually trivial. writeFile supports Base64 as an encoding, canvas.toDataUrl() returns Base64. So writing it is trivial, and decoding the Base64 in memory isn;t much harder.

describe('The Problem', () => {
    it('gets the image from a canvas', async () => {
        const c = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = c.getContext('2d')
        c.height = 10
        c.width = 10
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(127,0, 127)'
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
        ctx.lineTo(10, 5)
        ctx.stroke()

        const s = c.toDataURL()
        fs.writeFileSync('image.png', s.substring(s.indexOf(',')+1), {encoding: 'base64'})
        
    });

